# Twitter search API results results['text'] value does not have the a href tags

Tags: search, twitter

Twitter search API results returned like the below values

```
(                        
                    [source] => <a href="http://twitter.com/">web</a>
                    [text] => #prabhu linked into #apptivo via http://t.co/eWTJLj6Y
                    [to_user_id] => 
                    [to_user_id_str] => 
)
```

Here, 
[text] => #prabhu linked into #apptivo via http://t.co/eWTJLj6Y

we don't have the  tags for the "http://t.co/eWTJLj6Y" url and #prabhu (hash tag)

how can we get the urls for "http://t.co/eWTJLj6Y" url and #prabhu?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse them for URLs with a URL regex and add link and the same with hashtags (`/(#\w+)\b/` should do it).